# How to apply a constructor in an hypothesis?

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic

I am trying to prove the following theorem

```
Theorem subseq_subset : forall l1 l2, subseq l1 l2 -> sublist l1 l2.
```

with  the inductive type subseq :

```
Inductive subseq {A:Type} : list A -> list A -> Prop :=
| SubNil   : forall (l:list A), subseq  nil l
| Sub_both : forall (s l:list A) (x:A), subseq  s l -> subseq s (x::l)
| Sub_right : forall (s l: list A) (x:A), subseq s l -> subseq (x::s) (x::l).
```

and the definition of sublist:

```
 Definition sublist (l1 l2 : list A) : Prop := forall x : A, In x l1 -> In x l2.
```

this is the proof i started to do

```
Theorem subseq_subset : forall l1 l2, subseq l1 l2 -> sublist l1 l2.
Proof.
intros.

unfold sublist. intros.
induction l2.
+ inversion H in H0. simpl. simpl in H0. assumption.
+ apply in_cons. apply IHl2.
Qed.
```

i have this context now

```
1 subgoals
l1 : list A
a : A
l2 : list A
H : subseq l1 (a :: l2)
x : A
H0 : In x l1
IHl2 : subseq l1 l2 -> In x l2
______________________________________(1/1)
subseq l1 l2
```

i thought to apply sub_right on H so i can end the proof with assumption but `apply sub_right in H` is not working. Is this possible? and how can i end this proof?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that you stated definition

```
Inductive subseq {A:Type} : list A -> list A -> Prop :=
| SubNil   : forall (l:list A), subseq  nil l
| Sub_both : forall (s l:list A) (x:A), subseq  s l -> subseq s (x::l)
| Sub_right : forall (s l: list A) (x:A), subseq s l -> subseq (x::s) (x::l).
```

uses uppercase for the branches, so it would be `apply Sub_right in H`. Furthermore I think you switched the `both` and `right` branches. For the rest of this answer I'll assume the definition is

```
Inductive subseq {A:Type} : list A -> list A -> Prop :=
| subNil   : forall (l:list A), subseq  nil l
| sub_right : forall (s l:list A) (x:A), subseq  s l -> subseq s (x::l)
| sub_both : forall (s l: list A) (x:A), subseq s l -> subseq (x::s) (x::l).
```

Now to your actual question. When you say that `apply sub_right in H` doesn't work, what error message do you get? Coq told me that it couldn't find an `x`. This makes sense: if you are applying a theorem that has an `x` on the right-hand-side and no `x` on the left-hand-side, then Coq cannot guess which `x` to use. You can explicitly pick an `x` by saying `apply (sub_right _ _ x) in H`.

That said, I don't see how to complete your proof from where you are. I think you need an induction hypothesis. For example, if you're trying to prove `subseq l1 (x :: l2) -> sublist l1 (x :: l2)`, it would be nice to know that `subseq l1 l2 -> sublist l1 l2`. You can achieve this by using induction *on the proof of subseq l1 l2* instead of on one of the lists:

```
intros l1 l2 subseql1l2.
unfold sublist.
induction subseql1l2.
...
```

This gives you three nice cases that can be intuitively seen to be true. In order to prove them you will need some facts about `In` and lists, which you can look for by using, for example, `Search In (_ :: _).`